# Error executing docker file in spring boot maven project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dockerfile

Facing problems in docker file (spring boot maven project). When running docker file, it gives an error "The command '/bin/sh -c mvn -f pom.xml clean package' returned a non-zero code: 1". However if I directly execute the command 'mvn -f pom.xml clean package', I do not get any error.

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-slim AS build
RUN mkdir -p /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY pom.xml /workspace
COPY src /workspace/src
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:8-alpine
COPY --from=build /workspace/target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Please help on the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use experimental feature cache to speed up building process

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental
```

you dont need to run mkdir

```
RUN mkdir -p /workspace
```

just workdir is enought

```
WORKDIR /workspace
```

you can copy folder by

```
COPY . .
```

and add .dockerignore file from preventing not build related files and folders

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2/repository mvn -e -B clean package - 
Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

change

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

to

```
CMD ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

maven output will be helpfull to detect what exactly is wrong.

Comment: ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 4: Unknown flag: mount

Comment: As I said `RUN --mount=type=cache,` is experimental feature, so you need set enviroment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` before build. You can read more here https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/